How to display math symbols in PDF bookmark
I'm writing a section title including math symbols on Overleaf. I have used \texorpdfstring to aviod errors. But I don't know how to display these math symbols correctly in PDF bookmarks. I did read many posts on StackExchange, which suggested to fill out Unicode characters in the second {} of \texorpdfstring {}{} to solve this problem. But I don't know how to translate math symbols into unicode characters. Are there any resources/documents showing the relationship between the two stuff?
The codes I'm writing is the following:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}

\section{The case of \texorpdfstring {$L_2^* \left(x_n \right)$, $\forall x_n \in\left(\sigma_1, \sigma_2 \right)$}{.}}

\end{document}

Any answers and comments are welcome.

Untested, but if you compile once and then copy the section header in the pdf and paste it there, does it work?

@mickep thanks for your comment. This is indeed what NBur has done in the answer below. It seems to be the simplest way. But I'm wondering if we can show these math symbols better (to display superscripts/subscripts) in the bookmark.

The commands for the subscripts and superscripts can be found in puenc.def.
\documentclass{article}
\def\textBeta{}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}

\section{The case of \texorpdfstring{$L_2^* \left(x_n \right)$, $\forall x_n \in\left(\sigma_1, \sigma_2 \right)$}%
  {L\texttwoinferior\textasteriskcentered(x\textninferior), \textforall x\textninferior\textin (\textsigma\textoneinferior, \textsigma\texttwoinferior)}}

\end{document}


Related: pdfstring for math symbols

Many thanks for your answer. Can you place * on the superscript of L? Btw, is this the best solution of displaying math symbols in the bookmark? May I ask if there is other ways to show these symbols in math mode as they are shown in the main text?

I think there are  two ways to display math symbols in the bookmark.

Use the commands for the unicode symbols. This is fast if you remember the commands' name.
Use the unicode symbols directly. This is intuitive but tedious in my opinion.


I can't put the asterisk right above the subscript (₂).

Thanks. So what is the second way to show these symbols? Is it possible to make math symbols shown in math mode in the bookmark? The plain format does not look very nice.

The second way is what @Nbur has shown in his updated answer.

@YaHe pdf bookmarks are by definition plain text, that is what pdf specifies, latex can not change that. You can (in current versions of pdf) use unicode rather than just the original PDF encoding but you can not use any math layout commands

The simplest way, IMHO, is to

compile once your tex file as you provided it,
copy the math part of the title
paste in the tex and adapt
recompile

With your MWE, here is what I get:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\bfseries{\boldmath}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  
  \section{The case of \texorpdfstring {$L_2^* \left(x_n \right)$, $\forall x_n \in\left(\sigma_1, \sigma_2 \right)$}{L2*(xn), ∀ xn ∈ (σ1, σ2)}}
  
\end{document}

BTW, I added boldmath in the title.


Edit
You can improve the subscripts and superscripts by copying/pasting from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts.
\section{The case of \texorpdfstring {$L_2^* \left(x_n \right)$, $\forall x_n \in\left(\sigma_1, \sigma_2 \right)$}{L₂*(xₙ), ∀ xₙ ∈ (σ₁, σ₂)}}



Bookmarks can contain only plain unicode text, one symbol after the other. That means that not every math formula can be represented faithfully. Complicated superscripts, double superscripts, fractions, diagrams, etc have to be translated to plain text. How you do that depends a lot on the actual equation.
You can try to simply insert the unicode characters in the "PDF" part of \textofpdfstring. The easiest way to get most math unicode symbols is to compile the equation once with lualatex and unicode-math and then to copy&paste the text:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$L_2^* \left(x_n \right)$, $\forall x_n \in\left(\sigma_1, \sigma_2 \right)$
\end{document}

This then gives this

But as can be clearly seen it is not perfect: Superscript and subscripts are wrong. You then have to adjust manually, in your case by exchanging them with existing unicode text super- and subscript characters to get some acceptable looking result:
{*₂(ₙ), ∀ₙ ∈ (₁, ₂)}


Other options are to use some system that writes equations as plain text, e.g. https://github.com/MurrayIII/UnicodeMathML.
Or you avoid math in the bookmarks and write instead the name or description of the equation: imho that is better anyway as it makes navigation easier for a user with e.g. a screen reader.
